# How to print multiple System.out.println() on one line

Tags: java

I would like the output to be

```
**c**d*c
```

not to be

```
*
*
c
*
*
d
*
c
```

knowing that each character from the previous is printed using System.out.println() in hangman game code

Comment: Yes. Go ahead. Do you have any questions ? use  `System.out.print()`  instead `System.out.println()`

Comment: What did you do for your output ?

Answer (score 8):

Do `System.out.print()` instead

`println()` means print and new line